# Graphs menu missing on github

Tags: github

I used to be able to do Graphs menu > Network
to see a great graph of branches and transactions.
But now it's gone.

I'm still a novice at github.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They changed graph menu to insight menu.
Check it.